# Creating Instance of trait

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
scala> trait Bip[T]
defined trait Bip

scala> trait Bop[R <: Bip[R]] 
defined trait Bop
```

My understanding is that `R`'s upper limit is the type `Bip[R]`. If so, it's not clear to me what type can satisfy this constraint.

For example, if I want to create a `Bop[Int]`, then doesn't the following `least upper bound` resolve to `Any`?

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> lub(List(typeOf[Int], typeOf[Bip[Int]]))
res22: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Any
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an example of F-bounded polymorphism (there's a brief explanation [here](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html)).  You cannot create things like `Bop[Int]` but it's easy to create a new recursively-defined type that satisfies the constraint:

```
scala> case class Foo(bar: String) extends Bip[Foo]
defined class Foo

scala> trait Baz extends Bop[Foo]
defined trait Baz
```

So the only types that can satisfy `R` are those that are defined to extend `Bip` parameterized to themselves.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the term. Here's a nice blog post from @tpolecat - http://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html.